# Store value in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

```
public class GetCurrentLocation {
    String address;

    public String GetLocation(Context context) {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy =
            new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        GPSService mGPSService = new GPSService(context);
        mGPSService.getLocation();

        if (mGPSService.isLocationAvailable == false) {

        } else {
            // Getting location co-ordinates
            double latitude = mGPSService.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mGPSService.getLongitude();

            address=String.valueOf(latitude+""+longitude);

            System.out.print(String.valueOf(latitude));
            System.out.print(String.valueOf(longitude));

            //address = mGPSService.getLocationAddress();
        }
        return address;
    }
}
```

How to store values in SharedPreferences? The values are latitude and longitude. Then I want to retrieve them in fragment, any idea?

Comment: You have read the documentation about shared preferences, which explains very simply how to use it? At least try to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
     SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("AppPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor PrefsEditor = preferences.edit();

    //set value
    Double longitude latitude,
    PrefsEditor.putString("latitude", longitude+"");
    PrefsEditor.putString("longitude", latitude+"");


    //get value
    String latitude_value=preferences.getString("latitude", "");    
    String longitude_value=preferences.getString("longitude", "");
```

Comment: getSharedPreferences cannot resloved

Comment: do like this: `getActivity().getSharedPreferences()`

Comment: if you are using in fragment then use getActivity().getSharedPreferences

Comment: SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("AppPrefs", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);

Answer (score 0):

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor PrefsEditor = preferences.edit();

    //set value to pref
    Double longitude latitude,
    PrefsEditor.putString("latitude", longitude+"");
    PrefsEditor.putString("longitude", latitude+"");


    //get value from pref in fragment

    SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String latitude_value=preferences.getString("latitude", "");    
    String longitude_value=preferences.getString("longitude", ""); 

    prefsEditor.apply()
```

Comment: How can retrive this value in fragment